# INNER JOIN same table for results in one single row

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `product` like (minimal fields):

```
manufacturer_id | sku
33              | Icedisk 1<:=:>DEEPCOOL
33              | DP-IDISK1<:=:>DEEPCOOL
```

I want to get through one SELECT statement both sku's like: `Icedisk 1<:=:>DEEPCOOL | DP-IDISK1<:=:>DEEPCOOL`.

I've tried, with no luck:

```
SELECT p1.sku AS sku1, p2.sku AS sku2 
FROM `product` p1 INNER JOIN `product` p2 ON p1.manufacturer_id=p2.manufacturer_id 
WHERE p1.sku LIKE 'Icedisk 1<:=:>%' AND p2.sku='DP-IDISK1<:=:>%'
```

If I search for each product individually (like `SELECT`sku`FROM`product`WHERE`sku`LIKE 'DP-IDISK1<:=:>%'` ) it works fine. What am I missing here?

Many thanks!

Comment: change `AND p2.sku='DP-IDISK1<:=:>%'` to `AND p2.sku LIKE 'DP-IDISK1<:=:>%'` and you will get the expected results

Comment: Damn! I was sure it was a minimal change, but I was bllind. Please post it as an answer so I can rate it. Many thanks!

Comment: FFS! What's wrong with the following query: `INSERT IGNORE INTO aa_mapare_produse (sku1,sku2) VALUES (SELECT p1.sku, p2.sku FROM product p1 INNER JOIN product p2 ON p1.manufacturer_id=p2.manufacturer_id WHERE p1.sku LIKE 'E-Golf<:=:>%' AND p2.sku LIKE 'DP-EGOLF-WH<:=:>%' )` ... I'm getting "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT p1.sku, p2.sku FROM product p1 INNER JOIN product p2 ON p1.manufacturer_i' at line 1" ... Definitely not a good day for programming.

Comment: see below - maybe also add that second part of your question to the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `AND p2.sku='DP-IDISK1<:=:>%'` to `AND p2.sku LIKE 'DP-IDISK1<:=:>%'` and you will get the expected results.

As for your comment to your question (please add it to the question) its simple - you dont need to use `values` and you don't need to wrap the `select` statement in parenthesis. instead of:

`INSERT IGNORE INTO aa_mapare_produse (sku1,sku2) VALUES (SELECT p1.sku, p2.sku FROM product p1 INNER JOIN product p2 ON p1.manufacturer_id=p2.manufacturer_id WHERE p1.sku LIKE 'E-Golf<:=:>%' AND p2.sku LIKE 'DP-EGOLF-WH<:=:>%' )`

It should be

`INSERT IGNORE INTO aa_mapare_produse (sku1,sku2) SELECT p1.sku, p2.sku FROM product p1 INNER JOIN product p2 ON p1.manufacturer_id=p2.manufacturer_id WHERE p1.sku LIKE 'E-Golf<:=:>%' AND p2.sku LIKE 'DP-EGOLF-WH<:=:>%'`

And that's far more likely to work